# Does Schema.org have actual data or just provide schemas?

Tags: rdf, schema.org

I'm currently trying to understand RDF and trying to use stuff provided by Schema.org.

However, I saw so many schema information there, but do they have actual data or Microdata to be downloaded as XML or other format that can be used?

I am new in this area.

Comment: What do you mean with "actual data"? In case of [Movie](http://schema.org/Movie), a list of all existing movies?

Comment: Yes.. That's what I mean..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, schema.org is a *vocabulary*. They don’t host data/content that uses this vocabulary (apart from example snippets).

You can ask for specific datasets on our sister site, 
[Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: So pull dataset from other websites, such as "Business", "Organization", etc.. And use the schema from schema?

Comment: @JudyJiang: Sorry, I don’t understand. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Sorry. I mean pull dataset such as "Local Business", "Organizations".. these objects from other data providers. Then apply the schemas to build the graph (nodes and edges between these objects)? Thx!

Comment: @JudyJiang: Sorry, it’s still not clear to me. I guess you need to give much more details and background in a separate question. -- When you parse a webpage that makes use of the schema.org vocabulary (e.g., giving data about the local business by using the `LocalBusiness` type), then you don’t need to "build" a graph, you just parse the RDFa/Microdata/JSON-LD/etc. When the content is *not* using schema.org, then you can describe it yourself using schema.org (or any other suitable vocabulary).